# What's the best command to discover an application's PID?

Tags: macos, bash

Just now, I encountered a bug in Google Chrome. For whatever reason, my Chrome tab, which was open to StackOverflow, created an infinite loop of "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" prompts.

I wanted to do a force-kill on terminal. But I had a hard time finding the PIDs for my Chrome application.

What is the simplest `ps` command (or any other command) to get the PIDs of your Chrome application on Mac OS X?

My best try was `ps aux | grep '/Applications/Google Chrome.app'` but I found the output hard to read. I would like to limit the columns to PID and command name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To control which columns are in the `ps` output, use the options `-o` (add columns) or `-O` (set columns). A list of columns is provided by `ps -L`.

So, in this case, `ps ax -o pid,comm` (without arguments) or `ps ax -o pid,args` (with arguments).

To increase column width, specify the `-w` argument twice, e.g. `ps axww -o pid,args`.